# How to have "import X" importing all modules of package, but "from X import Y1" only importing/evaluating the module Y1?

Tags: python, import, module

I have the following package/module structure:

```
X
|-> __init__.py
|-> y1.py
|-> y2.py
```

The functionality I want in my project is that when I do `import X` I get all the modules under the package `X` namespace: so, I can call `X.y1.functionA()` or `X.y2.functionB()`.

That is easy enough if I write `__init__.py` as:

```
import X.y1
import X.y2
```

Problem is, like this, if I do an `from X import y1` it still imports `y2` as well. But in this case I don't want to import (or even evaluated as someone pointed in the comments) `y2`, I really only want `y1` to get imported and evaluated.

How do I go about this?

Comment: If I recall correctly, it's not that y2 is imported, but it does get evaluated.  I assume that's what you're trying to avoid?

Comment: Oh. Yes, that was what I was observing, it was getting evaluated although not necessarily imported (I didn't check that). But yes, I would like it *not* to be evaluated as well.

Comment: I'm not entirely sure you can avoid it.  What is happening in y2 that you don't want to be evaluated.  Likely you could address the problem there.

Comment: Well, testing. If I there is something wrong with `y2`, but I am only interested in testing `y1`, I want to do a `from X import y1` and have the tests complete successfully without caring for `y2`.

Comment: Assuming your testing logic is outside of X, you shouldn't have any issues with `from X import y1`.  The tests will only look at y1.  Unless there is something executing in y2 that shouldn't, you should feel safe ignoring it.  However, if there *IS* something executing that shouldn't in y2, then I would look at abstracting that logic to not execute upon evaluation during import/startup.  That could mean moving logic into `if __name__ == '__main__':` or even just putting it in a function to be called later.